# Qt connect с разными аргументами

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Здравствуйте! Как сделать connect с разными аргументами (qint64 и int)?

```
connect(player, SIGNAL(positionChanged(qint64)), ui->clock, SLOT(display(int)));
```

> player - QMediaPlayer || clock - QLCDNumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так (синтаксис qt5). По идее должно автоматом приводиться

```
QObject::connect(player, &QMediaPlayer::positionChanged, ui->clock, &QLCDNumber::display);
```

**EDIT**

К сожалению, у QLCDNumber несколько слотов display (int, double). Какой именно использовать компилятору неясно и надо ему это явно указать:

```
QObject::connect(player, &QMediaPlayer::positionChanged, ui->clock, static_cast<void(QLCDNumber::*)(int)>(&QLCDNumber::display));
```

Или использовать лямбду

```
QObject::connect(player, &QMediaPlayer::positionChanged, this, [this](qint64 _arg)
{
ui->clock->display(static_cast<int>(_arg));
});
```

Что-нибудь из этого должно сработать =)